# Point to the left or right of 3D vector in a specifc plane?

Tags: vector, 3d, geometry

I am not sure if a question like this was asked before but i searched and didn't found what i am looking for.

I know how to determine if a point is to the left or right of a 2D line. but suppose we have a vector in 3D. of course a 3D vector passes through infinite planes, but suppose we chose one plane of them in which we are interested, and we have a specific point on this plane which we want to know if it lies to the left or right or on our vector (with respect to the chosen plane). how to do this ?

Comment: StackOverflow cannot work without feedback. You did not discuss in all your themes and did not accepted answers.

Comment: @MBo Thank you so much for saying that. I noticed that in the history of OP too. Is it me or nobody ever discusses anything anymore? I've written like 10 long and detailed answers in the past few days, but nobody seems to care. Not only don't they upvote/accept, even though clearly the answer has solved their problem, but if they reply (big if), then they talk to you like you owe them something. I'm sick of this. Anyway, nice answer. I shouldn't be like those that annoy me, so here's my upvote. An OP, give some feedback for ****'s sake.

Comment: sorry guys if you feel annoyed, when the thing that answers my question is not exactly in the answers on my question i leave the community to choose the best answer as they see, maybe i am wrong and i will give my feedback from now on. regarding this question, i concluded an approach that solved my problem which is: let the line be AB and the point be C, first find cross product AB × AC, let the result be vector V =(x, y, z). if x, y , z are all 0 then the point is on the line, otherwise the signs of x, y, z respectively represent the direction in which C is, continued in next comment.

Comment: @MohamedELTair  In all of you history, most of the answers have exactly answered the problem. I also believe it to be the case for the present question. The way you behave gives the impression that you just don't read the answer if it requires a little effort.

Comment: @MohamedELTair Also, you should realize that people who answer you do it for free. So it is extremely rude to ignore them.

Comment: bro, i read the answers fully, and it won't benefit me anything to say that the answer didn't answer my question while it answers. you may find in your perspective that it answers but i may see that you did't simplify it enough for example, and as i said i will give my feedback from now on to prevent this confusion. the rude thing is to call someone rude just because you don't want to underatand him well and just easily give assumptions that he ignored you, while this person (me) commented before to apologize for misunderstandings in this issue.

Comment: @MohamedELTair This is exactly what I'm talking about: you say 'you didn't simplify it enough". Well, then, ask me to do so! I'll be happy to explain (as would be other users), and we both would learn something. Feedback is not just upvotes/downvotes, it is saying to me that I'm wrong and having a conversation about the topic, and making the answer evolve. Thanks for finally giving feedback though :)

Comment: you are right and my feedback from now on will be provided, and thank you all for your efforts.
continuing my comment before the previous: the main reason i wanted to do this was to know if a point lies on a triangle in 3D, if triangle points are A, B, C and the point to be checked is D. I made cross products: AB X AD, BC X BD, CA X CD, let the cross product results be respectively vectors : V1 = (x1, y1, z1), V2 = (x2, y2, z2), V3 = (x3, y3, z3). if all xi (1<=i<=3) are >=0 or all are <=0, and all yi are >=0 or all are <=0, and all zi are >=0 or all are <=0, the point lies on the triangle.

Comment: but before this of course I check that the point D lies on the same plane as the triangle.

Comment: Ou, conversation has started :) Should say that both replies refer to the original question (as far as possible with inexact formulation) . But now author tells us about another problem. Is it a kind of `XY problem`? It is worth to make another question (approach with `if all xi (1<=i<=3) are >=0 or all are <=0` is probably defective for arbitrary planes)

Comment: To avoid conversation this is the last comment i will post to clarify what i mean, I said why i wanted to know the orientation thing, the idea i used is based on if at least one component (i or j or k) of the cross products calculated has changed sign (from +ve to -ve or vice versa) then the relative direction of the point to the 3D triangle side has changed so it is impossible for the point to be on the triangle, and the problem i was trying to solve (in competitive programming) got accepted based on this idea.

Comment: @Mohamed EL Tair  It is easy to check whether point D lies in plane ABC - dot product. It is easy to check whether point D lies inside triangle ABC - mixed product. But seems you don't need advices about different (perhaps simpler) approaches.

Comment: I appreciate any help but I didn't understand your approach much, for example in  mp = (AB x BC) . dot. N, i didn't know what you meant by the word dot in this context. maybe I had to ask you to avoid confusion.

Comment: `.dot.` here is dot product (scalar product of vectors). Mixed (triple scalar) product is described at linked wiki page.

Comment: @MBo: marked your answer, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly define orientation of that plane - for example, define main (forward) normal `N` - like `OZ` axis is normal for `OXY` plane.

If you have A,B,C triangle and claim that it is oriented counterclockwise, you can calculate forward plane normal as `N = AB x BC`

For points `A, B, D` in given plane calculate [mixed product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product)  (vector product of `AB` and `AD`, then scalar product of result and `N`)

```
 mp = (AB x AD) . dot. N
```

Sign of this value is positive, if vectors `AB, AD, N` form `right-handed` triplet and **D lies left to AB direction**

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive solution is to define a coordinate system for the plane as follows. Let's normalize the 3d vector in your question and call the resulting unit vector `v`, and let `x` be a point on your plane, whose unit normal we will denote as `n`. You can now chose a coordinate system centered at `x`, that is made by the three `3*1` unit vectors `v`, `n` and `b=v.crossProduct(n)`.

The idea is that if you express a point in this coordinate system, then if its `b` coordinate is negative, you can says that it is, say, on the left. So, if its `b` coordinate is positive, it will be on the right.

Obviously, if you have a point `q` expressed in this coordinates system, you can write its expression `q_w` in world coordinates using

```
  q_w=R*q+x
```

where the rotation matrix R is the matrix whose columns are the unit axes of the plane coordinate system:

```
  R=[v n b]
```

So, if you have a point `Q` in world coordinates, using the inverse of the relation above, you compute `transpose(R)*(Q-x)`, and look at whether the `b` coordinate is positive or negative.